# I cannot fetch data on search of next record into form which showing empty fields, first record is showing

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am fetching data from database into form based on input data.
For an example: In form, if I search for lastname, it should fetch lastname data. It has been success for all field search by using AND or OR operator buttons.

But problem faced in pagination where I am getting only one record but not getting another record as per search criteria.

Here, I am using template library to include pages.

[image]

here in above form image if i search of particular record by inputting text in any field should display in same view..and pagination links as per search records require

initial form is empty

**Model:**

```
public function search_record()

{
               $id= $this->input->get('id');
               $name= $this->input->get('lname');
               $fname= $this->input->get('fname');
               $pdate= $this->input->get('pdate');
               $adate= $this->input->get('adate');
               $client= $this->input->get('client');
               $bw= $this->input->get('bw');
               $color= $this->input->get('color');
               $digital= $this->input->get('digital');
               $famous= $this->input->get('famous');
               $place= $this->input->get('place');
               $concept= $this->input->get('concept');
               $thing= $this->input->get('thing');
               $oldid= $this->input->get('oldid');
               $note= $this->input->get('note');



//            $condition = array('id_photo' =>$id);
//            $condition2=array('lastname'=>$name);
//            $condition3=array('firstname'=>$fname);                    
//            $condition4=array('photo_date'=>$pdate);
//            

            $this->db->select('photo_id,lastname,firstname,bw,color,digital,famous,place,concept,thing,client,photo_date,add_date,note,id_photo');
            $this->db->from('tblphotomstr');
            $strWhere = "";
            if($id != NULL){
                $strWhere = "id_photo like "."'%$id%'";
            }
            if($name != NULL){
                $opt = $this->input->get('and');


                if($opt==1)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != "")
                        {
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." and lastname like "."'%$name%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "lastname like "."'%$name%'";
                    }
                }
                if($opt==2)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != ""){
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." or lastname like "."'%$name%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "lastname like "."'%$name%'";
                    }
                }
            }
            if($fname != NULL){
                $opt = $this->input->get('and');


                if($opt==1)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != "")
                        {
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." and firstname like "."'%$fname%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "firstname like "."'%$fname%'";
                    }
                }
                if($opt==2)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != ""){
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." or firstname like "."'%$fname%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "firstname like "."'%$fname%'";
                    }
                }
            }
            if($pdate != NULL){
                $opt = $this->input->get('and');


                if($opt==1)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != "")
                        {
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." and photo_date like "."'%$pdate%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "photo_date like "."'%$pdate%'";
                    }
                }
                if($opt==2)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != ""){
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." or photo_date like "."'%$pdate%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "photo_date like "."'%$pdate%'";
                    }
                }
            }
            if($adate != NULL){
                $opt = $this->input->get('and');


                if($opt==1)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != "")
                        {
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." and add_date like "."'%$adate%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "add_date like "."'%$adate%'";
                    }
                }
                if($opt==2)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != ""){
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." or add_date like "."'%$adate%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "add_date like "."'%$adate%'";
                    }
                }
            }
            if($client != NULL){
                $opt = $this->input->get('and');


                if($opt==1)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != "")
                        {
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." and client like "."'%$client%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "client like "."'%$client%'";
                    }
                }
                if($opt==2)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != ""){
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." or client like "."'%$client%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "client like "."'%$client%'";
                    }
                }
            }
            if($bw != NULL){
                $opt = $this->input->get('and');


                if($opt==1)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != "")
                        {
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." and client like "."'%$bw%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "client like "."'%$bw%'";
                    }
                }
                if($opt==2)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != ""){
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." or client like "."'%$bw%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "client like "."'%$bw%'";
                    }
                }
            }
            if($color != NULL){
                $opt = $this->input->get('and');


                if($opt==1)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != "")
                        {
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." and client like "."'%$color%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "client like "."'%$color%'";
                    }
                }
                if($opt==2)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != ""){
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." or client like "."'%$color%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "client like "."'%$color%'";
                    }
                }
            }
            if($digital != NULL){
                $opt = $this->input->get('and');


                if($opt==1)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != "")
                        {
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." and client like "."'%$digital%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "client like "."'%$color%'";
                    }
                }
                if($opt==2)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != ""){
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." or client like "."'%$digital%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "client like "."'%$digital%'";
                    }
                }
            }
            if($famous != NULL){
                $opt = $this->input->get('and');


                if($opt==1)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != "")
                        {
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." and client like "."'%$famous%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "client like "."'%$famous%'";
                    }
                }
                if($opt==2)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != ""){
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." or client like "."'%$digital%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "client like "."'%$digital%'";
                    }
                }
            }
            if($place != NULL){
                $opt = $this->input->get('and');


                if($opt==1)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != "")
                        {
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." and client like "."'%$place%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "client like "."'%$place%'";
                    }
                }
                if($opt==2)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != ""){
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." or client like "."'%$place%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "client like "."'%$place%'";
                    }
                }
            }
            if($concept != NULL){
                $opt = $this->input->get('and');


                if($opt==1)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != "")
                        {
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." and client like "."'%$concept%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "client like "."'%$concept%'";
                    }
                }
                if($opt==2)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != ""){
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." or client like "."'%$concept%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "client like "."'%$concept%'";
                    }
                }
            }
            if($thing != NULL){
                $opt = $this->input->get('and');


                if($opt==1)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != "")
                        {
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." and client like "."'%$thing%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "client like "."'%$thing%'";
                    }
                }
                if($opt==2)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != ""){
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." or client like "."'%$thing%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "client like "."'%$thing%'";
                    }
                }
            }
            if($oldid != NULL){
                $opt = $this->input->get('and');


                if($opt==1)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != "")
                        {
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." and client like "."'%$oldid%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "client like "."'%$oldid%'";
                    }
                }
                if($opt==2)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != ""){
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." or client like "."'%$oldid%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "client like "."'%$oldid%'";
                    }
                }
            }
            if($note != NULL){
                $opt = $this->input->get('and');


                if($opt==1)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != "")
                        {
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." and note like "."'%$note%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "note like "."'%$note%'";
                    }
                }
                if($opt==2)
                    {
                    if($strWhere != ""){
                        $strWhere = $strWhere." or note like "."'%$note%'";
                    }else{
                        $strWhere = "note like "."'%$note%'";
                    }
                }
            }
```

**controller:**

```
 public function search()
        {

            print_r($this->search_model->search_record());

            $limit = 1;
            $config["base_url"] = base_url('Home/search');
            $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('tblphotomstr');
            $config["per_page"] = $limit;
            $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
            $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
            $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
            $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<li class="active"><a>';
            $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
            $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
            $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            $offset = 0;
        if (!empty($_GET['per_page'])) {
            $pageNo = $_GET['per_page'];
            $offset = ($pageNo - 1) * $limit;
        }

            $data = array();
            $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);

            $data['records']= $this->search_model->search_record();
            print_r($data);
            $this->template->set('title', 'Edit Record');
            $this->template->load('default_layout', 'contents' , 'search', $data);

        }
```

Comment: pls post your entire model code and your pagination code - because i think all your get parameter are getting lost after clicking on page 2 or something like that... and another recommendation - you've to use the querybuilder properly - your entire query is totally insecure

Comment: in view i used  (<div class="pagination-links">
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links();?>
</div>).  i put my entire model code for searching record..pls guide me if any requirements..to posts

Comment: i update my query @sintakonte  with form image with some description...if not clear pls guide..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the profiler. ($this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);)  Enable it on your controller construct, so you will be see the results on every subfunction too.

It will be list all necessary data you need to find your problem ( get data, executed queries)

Hope it helps

Comment: i used ur query @alchalade....my get data got below lines... GET DATA $_GET['pfrom'] $_GET['pto'] $_GET['afrom'] $_GET['ato'] $_GET['and'] 2 $_GET['pdate'] $_GET['adate'] $_GET['lname'] aa $_GET['fname'] $_GET['client'] $_GET['bw'] $_GET['color'] $_GET['digital'] $_GET['id'] $_GET['oldid'] $_GET['note']